# Excel Formula Needed - if/then, based on 2 columns data

Tags: excel, formula

I need a formula that does this:

If A2 says "L", and B2 (date) is over 3 months ago, then say "Need to reach out!", if B2 (date) is less than 3 months ago but over 2.5 months ago, then say "Schedule a call!", and if B2 (date) is less than 2 months ago, say "Communications up to date."

OR

If A2 says "M", and B2 (date) is over 6 weeks ago, then say "Need to reach out!", if B2 (date) is less than 6 weeks ago ago but over 4 weeks ago ago, then say "Schedule a call!", and if B2 (date) is less than 4 weeks ago, say "Communications up to date."

OR

If A2 says "H", and B2 (date) is over 3 weeks ago, then say "Need to reach out!", if B2 (date) is less than 3 weeks ago ago but over 2 weeks ago ago, then say "Schedule a call!", and if B2 (date) is less than 2 weeks ago, say "Communications up to date."

AND if C2 says "scheduled" then say "Communication Scheduled"

Is this even possible?

Comment: Possible, but it won't be pretty. One clarification- what's your definition of a month? Does it have to be calender months, or will (for example) 12 weeks do for '3 months'?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (but it's not pretty):

```
=if(A2="L",
  if(now()-B2>=84,
    "Need to reach out!",
    if(now()-b2>=70,
      "Schedule a call!",
      if(now()-B2<56,
        "Communications up to date",
        ""
      )
    )
  ),
  if(A2="M",
    if(now()-b2>=42,
      "Need to reach out!",
      if(now()-b2>=28,
        "Schedule a call!",
        "Communications up to date"
      )
    ),
    if(A2="H",
      if(now()-b2>=21,
        "Need to reach out!",
        if(now()-b2>=14,
          "Schedule a call!",
          "Communications up to date"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)&
if(C2="scheduled",
  " - Communication Scheduled",
  ""
)
```

I'm assuming 12 weeks for 3 months, 10 weeks for 2.5 months, and 8 weeks for 2 months. They're specified in days in the formula, edit as required if not.

Comment: I'm comfortable with those assumptions, as well. Would this formula work in Google Sheets, as well, do you think?

Comment: It probably would, the IF and NOW functions are identical as far as I can tell, but I haven't used it so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I like using `INDEX` array formulas for pretty much everything and in this case I think it works nicely. Try setting up a table with the Types L, H, and M; the number of Days before today for each Type and condition; and the desired Message for each condition:

[image: Excel Formula]

The formula then is:

```
=INDEX(Table[Message],MATCH(A2&TRUE,Table[Type]&(TODAY()-B2>Table[Days]),0))
```

Note that this is an array formula and must be entered using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.